# How to merge/combine two rows within a column/Series in a DataFrame when the two rows' values are different?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I have a DataFrame, and one column is "lang" for "language."

Two different values in this column are "en" for "English" and "en-gb" for "British English."

There are numerous other values in this row, including "es" for "Spanish, "fr" for "French," and so on.

So it looks something like this:

```
user        lang       id

joe         en         77788
jim         en-gb      23323
pedro       es         12134
tom         en         53892
juan        es         24434
phillippe   fr         04211
george      en-gb      99999
```

For the purposes of my analysis, I want to count the 'en' and 'en-gb' values together as being the same "en" or "English" value. Perhaps I could put just this column into a Series and then count them as one, or I could change the "en-gb" values with "en."

Comment: You could do either using the `.replace` function... what are you asking exactly?

Comment: if the languages have two letters then you can use `df['lang'] = df['lang'].str[:2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first two letters you can use string slicing i.e .str[:2] So we can consider language divisions as one.

```
df['lang'].str[:2]
```

```
0    en
1    en
2    es
3    en
4    es
5    fr
6    en
Name: lang, dtype: object
```

Now you got the series store it in one of the columns like

```
df['new'] = df['lang'].str[:2]
```

Merge with key as new. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column using .str[:2] as Bharath suggested. If you want to keep the column unchanged, you can use groupby on that column directly.
Say you want to find the count of users for each language,

```
df_new = df.groupby(df.lang.str[:2]).user.count()
```

Or

```
df_new = df.groupby(df.lang.str.split('-').str[0]).user.count()
```

will return

```
lang
en    4
es    2
fr    1
```

And your original data is unaffected

Answer (score 0):

By using `replace`

```
df=df.replace({'en-gb':'en'})
df
Out[358]: 
        user lang     id
0        joe   en  77788
1        jim   en  23323
2      pedro   es  12134
3        tom   en  53892
4       juan   es  24434
5  phillippe   fr   4211
6     george   en  99999
```